# Finding limit when values of derivatives at a point are given

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponentiation

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be such that $f''$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ and $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0, f''(0)=-1$. The $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{x}\right)\right)^x}$ is .....

I did this using particular function $f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}2$ and got answer $\frac1e$, but how to do generally?

Comment: Take logs and proceed using the fact that $(1/t)\log(1+t)\to 1$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, do you mean something like $\lim e^{\ln f(\sqrt2/x)^x}$?

Comment: Well just take logs to get $x\log f(\sqrt{2}/x)$ and evaluate its limit, say $L$. Later exponentiate and get the final answer as $e^L$. You may note that $f(\sqrt{2}/x)\to f(0)=1$ and hence $(\log f(\sqrt{2}/x))/(f(\sqrt{2}/x)-1)\to 1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you very much for your big help (here as well as through your blog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Exponentiate the expression and express it in a form wherein you can use L'Hopital's rule. $$ \exp \ln\Biggl(f\biggl( \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{x} \biggr)\Biggr)^x=\exp x\ln \Biggl(f\biggl( \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{x} \biggr)\Biggr)=\exp \dfrac{\ln\Biggl(f\biggl( \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{x} \biggr) \Biggr)}{1/x}$$Note that now you can simply make  use of L'Hopital's rule and rules of differentiation to evaluate this limit. You shouldn't be getting $1/e$, the answer is $1$.

Comment: My books back sol is so misleading! and IIT JAM solutions too :(   Thanks a lot man.